# SQL code to delete one entry from table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have one code for updating information on table on SQL and I am trying to use the same code with minor modifications to make it delete but it is not deleting. I cannot find anything that i am missing here.

```
    <html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<?php

$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db('my_db6');

$query = "SELECT * FROM emp";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

?>


<form method="post" action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>">
<table width="400" border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2">
<tr>

<?php 

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {

$ename = $row['ename'];
$empno = $row['empno'];
$position = $row['position'];
?>


<td width="100"></td>
<td><?=$ename?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100">E-Name</td>
<td><input name="ename" type="text" value="<?=$ename?>"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100">Employee Number</td>
<td><input name="empno" type="text" value="<?=$empno?>"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100">Position</td>
<td><input name="position" type="text" value="<?=$position?>"></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
<tr>
<td width="100"> </td>
<td> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100"> </td>
<td>
<input name="update" type="submit" id="update" value="Update">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
<?php

if(isset($_POST['update']))
{

$ename = $_POST['ename'];
$empno = $_POST['empno'];
$position = $_POST['position'];

$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE EMP SET ename = '$ename', empno = '$empno', position = '$position' WHERE ename = '$ename'");

echo "Updated data successfully\n";

}


?>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is the code of delete i am trying to make :

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<?php

$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db('my_db6');

$query = "SELECT * FROM emp";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

?>


<form method="post" action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>">
<table width="400" border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2">
<tr>

<?php 

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {

$ename = $row['ename'];
$empno = $row['empno'];
$position = $row['position'];
?>


<td width="100"></td>
<td><?=$ename?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100">E-Name</td>
<td><input name="ename" type="text" value="<?=$ename?>"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100">Employee Number</td>
<td><input name="empno" type="text" value="<?=$empno?>"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100">Position</td>
<td><input name="position" type="text" value="<?=$position?>"></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
<tr>
<td width="100"> </td>
<td> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100"> </td>
<td>
<input name="delete" type="submit" id="delete" value="delete">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
<?php

if(isset($_POST['delete']))
{

$ename = $_POST['ename'];
$empno = $_POST['empno'];
$position = $_POST['position'];

$sql = mysql_query("DELETE EMP SET ename = '', empno = '', position = '' WHERE ename = '$ename'");

echo "Deleted data successfully\n";

}


?>
</body>
</html>
```

however it doesn't make any changes in the SQL data table entry or deleting

Comment: Do you think your delete query is coreect?

Comment: Instead of dumping code on SO, try debugging.

Comment: `delete from table_name where some_col = 'some val'`

Comment: First: Make sure you escape your query parameters (mysql_query("UPDATE EMP SET ename = '$ename'...). Bad users could inject code if they change $ename to some SQL code.

Also: Update & Delete work a bit different. Use DELETE FROM EMP WHERE ename = '$ename'

Comment: @MitchWheat, If i did not try to debug I wouldn't come and ask here for help.

Comment: @PascalRaszyk Thank you sir for your clarification about the injection . my knowledge about SQL is few days only and I am trying my best to get a grab of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this to delete an entry:

```
mysql_query("DELETE FROM `emp` WHERE `ename`='$ename'");
```

If you want to edit an entry:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE `emp` SET `ename`='', `empno`='', `position`='' WHERE `ename`='$ename'");
```

I recommend you escape `$ename` before you use it in the query, you can do that like this:

```
$ename = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['ename']);
```

Comment: Your recommendations as very useful to me, thank you so much sir. I managed to delete the entry. I was so close to it though .

Answer (score 0):

I reckon your delete syntax is wrong. I'm no expert in MySQL, but it doesn't make sense to specify column values in a delete. Try

```
DELETE FROM emp WHERE ename = '$ename'
```

And as I now see a couple people have also mentioned in comments, it's very critical that you move to using parameterized queries. This approach is currently vulnerable to very serious SQL Injection attacks.